# AngularJs and landing page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

A landing page is often totally different than the look and feel of other pages.

Basically, with the default routing mechanism of angular, `index.html` could have an `ng-view` in order to display the various pages.
There is not concept of "conditions" with this ng-view.

Indeed, what if I want to specify some navigation bar to all pages but landing page?

Should I "include" a navigation bar to each of those templates, breaking DRY principle?

Comment: Or don't use angular for landing pages. Just take them to your app after they click the call to action or *continue to site*

Comment: @ogc-nick I thought about this, but why forcing a refresh if an Angular solution could exist. The user experience might be improved (no CSS, JS to fetch again etc..)

Comment: In my particular situation my landing page isn't a static page and I would like to have access to angular features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that by using angular-ui-router https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

With Angular UI Router You can define states instead but you need to pub/sub the state back to your navigation component.

Angular ui Router allows you to nest views so you don't need to put the navigation outside of the view which would result in reloading the page being out of your view.

Just a note ui router is using ui-sref directive to navigate instead of ng-href. This could be a lot of work for reforging your project But I believe it worth it.

About changing your Navigation.
You can have your navigation wrapped in an ng-if or ng-show directive or you can have a completely different base template on your / , /home state.

Cheers

Comment: Actually, my real scenario is that I have a different navbar (bootstrap's component) for my landing page. So I played with the current location in an `ng-class` to show or hide the expected classes, regarding if user is on the landing page or on others. However, in some circonstance, when Angular has not been loading yet, I have some delay for displaying the right navbar. (using ng-cloak would not be very UX)  Hope Angular ui-router can help :)

Comment: If you are heavily depended on bootstrap have a look on that http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. I suggest a navbar directive or a view, whichever is easier for you.

Comment: Yes I use it for other components like modals, except for the navbar, that doesn't bring an exceptional benefit. That would not alter the choice of this post's solution by the way :) => I would have the same issue

Comment: I have to agree with that. However helps if you are lazy :P. I think you'll be fine with the ui-router, are you using angular's pub/sub?

Comment: Nop, I never used angular's pub/sub. So does it make sense also for you to have the landing page be part of the SPA/Angular process? Regarding the comment above of @ogc-nick

Comment: If you meant pub/sub = broadcast events or emit events, so yes I used it.

Comment: If you aim on a SPA, the user is passing through the main page again during your session, I strongly disagree with ogc-nick. You should never reload the page in that case.

But, it has to do with your project's behaviour. If you just need a front page and the angular app a self contained experience, the user never returns to the main page as long as that experience lasts, then ogc-nick's suggestion is the way.

Yes I meant the inbuilt support. I suggest to read that blogpost for that http://eburley.github.io/2013/01/31/angularjs-watch-pub-sub-best-practices.html